# Getting error (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError) while installing Rails or gem update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I want to install Ruby on Rails in my laptop using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I've installed Ruby, but when I trying to install Rails with `sudo gem install rails`, i'm getting error message

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/websocket- extensions-0.1.3.gemspec.rz)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you install `ruby` with `sudo` ? If not try without `sudo`

Comment: @ts: How would `sudo` affect DNS name resolution?

Comment: May be [this](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/26201-gemremotefetcherunknownhosterror) will help.

Comment: @ts yes,while i try without `sudo` terminal showing error FilePermission

Answer (score 0):

Disable `IPv6` and retry. It should work.